# Is there a way to add a different number to each row in a numpy array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, data-science

I want to add a different number to each row of the matrix below.

```
array([[  6,   6,   6,   6],
       [  1,  -5, -11, -17],
       [  1,   7,  13,  19]], dtype=int64)
```

For example I want to add this array to the matrix:

```
array([-4, -3,  0])
```

Add the -4 of the array to the first row so it will be `array([2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64)`

The whole matrix should then look like this:

```
array([[  2,   2,   2,   2],
       [ -2,  -8, -14, -20],
       [  1,   7,  13,  19]], dtype=int64)
```

I could of course transform the 1d array to a matrix, but I wanted to know if there is maybe another option.

Comment: Add an empty dimension to the 1d array and you will have a column vector which will implicitly be broadcasted when you add the two together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in several ways:

1. Using `.reshape`: it will create a "column-vector" instead of a "row-vector"

```
a + b.reshape((-1,1))
```

2. Creating a new array then transposing it:

```
a + np.array([b]).T
```

3. Using `numpy.atleast_2d`:

```
a + np.atleast_2d(b).T
```

All of them with the same output:

```
array([[  2,   2,   2,   2],
       [ -2,  -8, -14, -20],
       [  1,   7,  13,  19]])
```

---

**Performance**

```
%%timeit 
a = np.random.randint(0,10,(2000,100)) 
b = np.random.randint(0,10,2000) 
a + b.reshape((-1,1)) 
#3.39 ms ± 43.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit 
a = np.random.randint(0,10,(2000,100)) 
b = np.random.randint(0,10,2000) 
a + np.array([b]).T
#3.4 ms ± 81.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit 
a = np.random.randint(0,10,(2000,100))
b = np.random.randint(0,10,2000)
a + np.atleast_2d(b).T
#3.37 ms ± 58.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Specifying the ```out``` keyword will make it slightly faster,  assuming that in-place operations are allowed ```np.add(a, b[:,None], out=a)```.